# Proper use of defaultOutputToParentFlow in dsl route

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to set up a default route to process a message based on a header value:

```
public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
           .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory)
                    .destination(queueName))

           .enrichHeaders(...) // set the status header ("failed", "success" or another value)

           // header-based router
           .route("headers.status", // "success", "failed", "running", ...
                   r -> r.subFlowMapping("failed",  failureFlow()) // one-way flow
                         .subFlowMapping("success", successFlow()) // one-way flow
                          // ignore other status values, such as "running"
                         .ignoreSendFailures(true)
                         .defaultOutputToParentFlow())
            .nullChannel();
}
```

Messages with header status "success" and "failed" are processed as expected, but for other statuses, Spring looks for a channel named (for instance) "running", which is indeed not defined, and I get the following exception:

```
2022-11-08 14:11:20.202  WARN 1 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'running'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'running' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'running' available
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:245) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addChannel(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:282) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addChannelFromString(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:268) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addChannelKeyToCollection(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:327) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addToCollection(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:297) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.determineTargetChannels(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:206) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:177) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:151) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:429) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.send(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:509) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:345) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:331) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:270) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'running' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'running' available
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:118) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:45) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:241) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'running' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:88) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar!/:5.5.15]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

What's the correct way to set a default route to ignore those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.noChannelKeyFallback()`.

```java
/**
 * By default, if a resolved channel key does not exist in the channel map, the key
 * itself is used as the channel name, which we will attempt to resolve to a channel.
 * Invoke this method to disable this feature. This could be useful to prevent
 * malicious actors from generating a message that could cause the message to be
 * routed to an unexpected channel, such as one upstream of the router, which would
 * cause a stack overflow.
 * @return the router spec.
 * @since 5.2
 */
public RouterSpec<K, R> noChannelKeyFallback() {
```

Comment: Great! Do I still need `.ignoreSendFailures(true)` or is it irrelevant for the current purpose?

Comment: It depends on whether or not you want to ignore exceptions thrown by your success and/or failure flows.